# Wicket: AjaxLazyLoadPanel hangs after rendering first panel

Tags: java, ajax, wicket

I'm using a Wicket AjaxLazyLoadPanel to render a list of items (each is its own panel).  It works fine *except* when you navigate to the page in a fresh browser session (start browser up, go straight to this page without visiting any other pages in the app).  When you do this, it renders the first item, but shows wait indicators for the other 12 forever.

Is this a bug in Wicket?  I'm using version 1.4.9

**Edit:**
Here is the way the LazyLoadPanel is being used.  `getLazyLoadComponent()` only gets called once the first time you hit the page:

```
public void populateItem(final Item<ListSearchRow> item) {
  item.add(new AjaxLazyLoadPanel("result") {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public Component getLazyLoadComponent(String markupId) {
      return new ListResult(markupId, item.getModel());
    }  
  });
}
```

Comment: The jsessionid isn't too likely the problem.  It might help to post the code where you use the AjaxLazyLoadPanel.

Comment: The jsessionid is on the url in first case because the session is new and the cookie not set yet. It's normal that it is attached to the url for the first request because the server doesn't know if the client will accept the cookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Editted as per comments below***:

Have you tried with a different version for wicket(-extentions)? It's caused me problems with the `AjaxLazyLoadPanel` as well before:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
    <artifactId>wicket</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.12</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
    <artifactId>wicket-extensions</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.12</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Switching to 1.4.2 didn't help.  Is that the specific version that has fixed the problem for you in the past?  I'm using Wicket version 1.4.9

Comment: Switching wicket and wicket-extensions to 1.4.12 fixed the problem.  Maybe change your answer to note that switching both versions may be necessary so that others can use the info.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Updated the answer: If this works for you the answer should reflect that.. The issue I had with the AjaxLazyLoadPanel was that the spinners wouldn't disappear in a similar situation (ALLP inside a repeater).. Switching *back* the version number fixed  it in my case.. Perhaps I should now try it with version 1.4.12.. But anyway: Glad I could help!